# hiding and showing array of images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So I have an array of images, which I would like to hide or show on a click of a button.
right now when I try to hide the image, it will hide the entire array.

```
 import "./main.css";
 import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
 import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
 import {
  faCircleChevronLeft,
  faCircleChevronRight,
  faCircleXmark,
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
const Main = ({ galleryImages }) => {
  const [slideNumber, setSlideNumber] = useState(0);
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
  const [pics, setPics] = useState([]);
  const [show, toggleShow] = useState(true);
// buttons next to name of diff charts (hide/show chart)
  const handleOpenModal = (index) => {
    setSlideNumber(index);
    setOpenModal(true);
  };

  const removeImage = (id) => {
    setPics((oldState) => oldState.filter((item) => item.id !== id));
  };

// const hide = () => {
//     setShow(false)
// }
const handleCloseModal = () => {
    setOpenModal(false)
}
useEffect(()=> {
    setPics(galleryImages)
},[]);
  return (
    <div>
     <button onClick={() => toggleShow(!show)}>toggle: {show ? 'show' : 'hide'}</button>    

      {show && 
      <div>
        {pics.map((pic) => {
            return (
                <div style = {{marginBottom:'100px'}}>
                    {pic.id}
                    <img
                    src={pic.img}
                    width='500px'
                    height='500px'
                    />
                    <button onClick ={() => removeImage(pic.id)}>Delete</button>

                    </div>
            )
        })}
        </div>
```

I tried making a state component to try to hide and show the images, however it will hide the entire array instead of the individual image

Comment: I'm not a react programmer, but where are you getting that oldState variable from? shouldn't that be `pics` so instead of `setPics((oldState) => oldState.filter((item) => item.id !== id));` it'd be `setPics((pics) => pics.filter((item) => item.id !== id));`? Or maybe `galleryImages`?

Comment: @Kathara the (oldState) is just a reference to the current state before the setState execution happens so that the data can be accessed, usually for keeping data from prevState => newState.

Comment: @JackEcuyer interesting and thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Kathara I probably didn't clarify it's use very well as it's a relatively new concept for me as well. If you want to get a good understanding this is worth a read: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Answer (score 0):

i would add a show var to the galleryImages array and then set it so you get control of each image like this

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

import "./main.css";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  faCircleChevronLeft,
  faCircleChevronRight,
  faCircleXmark,
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

function Main({ galleryImages }) {
  const [slideNumber, setSlideNumber] = useState(0);
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
  const [pics, setPics] = useState([]);

  // buttons next to name of diff charts (hide/show chart)

  const toggleShow = ({ id, show }) => {
    setPics((oldState) =>
      oldState.map((item) => {
        if (item.id !== id) return item;
        return { ...item, show: !show };
      })
    );
  };

  const removeImage = (id) => {
    setPics((oldState) => oldState.filter((item) => item.id !== id));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setPics(
      galleryImages.map((galleryImage) => {
        return { ...galleryImage, show: true };
      })
    );
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {pics.map((pic) => {
          return (
            <>
              <button
                onClick={() => toggleShow({ show: pic.show, id: pic.id })}
              >
                toggle: {pic.show ? "show" : "hide"}
              </button>
              {pic.show && (
                <div style={{ marginBottom: "100px" }}>
                  {pic.id}
                  <img src={pic.img} width="500px" height="500px" />
                  <button onClick={() => removeImage(pic.id)}>Delete</button>
                </div>
              )}
            </>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

`

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the option to hide individual pics, to accomplish this you are correct in your **state component** approach.
First you can create a pic **component** that has its own state with a hide/show button:

```
export default function Pic({pic}) {
    const [showPic, setShowPic] = useState(true);
    const handleClick = () => {setShowPic(!showPic)}
    return (
        <div>
            <div style={showPic ? {display : "block"} : {display : "none"}}>
                <img
                src={pic.img}
                width='500px'
                height='500px'
                />    
            </div>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>{showPic ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Next, you can import this component into your main file

`import Pic from 'location/Pic.js';`

and map each pic to a `<Pic>` component.

```
{pics.map((pic) => <Pic pic={pic} key={pic.id}/>)}
```

Now the images will be shown each with their own **Hide/Show** button that can toggle their display with the state contained within each `<Pic/>` component. This is good practice because toggling one image will not cause a **re-render** of the entire image gallery.